# VB Uncheck all checked checkboxes in forms

Tags: vb.net

This is my form1, it contains lots of checkboxes and a button, to show the form2:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form2.show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here is my form2, also it contains lot of checkboxes and a button, for unchecking all the checkboxes on form1 and on form2:

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'code for clearing all the checkboxes, I don't know how to do it
    End Sub
End Class
```

My question is: how can I make a code in Form2.Button1 for unchecking all the checkboxes in the Form1, Form2 and even other forms??

---

I tried this code, that unchecks only the checkboxes in the form where is it placed:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each cc As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf cc Is CheckBox Then
            DirectCast(cc, CheckBox).Checked = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Maybe I can do that by editing this code.. I don't know
Thank you all in advance

Comment: You would need a reference to all currently-instantiated forms.  So you'd have to track that globally somewhere in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got a solution:

```
    For Each cc As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf cc Is CheckBox Then
            DirectCast(cc, CheckBox).Checked = False
        End If
    Next
    For Each cc As Control In Form1.Controls
        If TypeOf cc Is CheckBox Then
            DirectCast(cc, CheckBox).Checked = False
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a list of open forms in a central location, when any form is created it should add itself to the list and when disposed, remove itself (you can inherit all your forms from a common base form that does this)

Then you can give all forms to a similar method that iterates through them and does the job.

Also, please note that your code does not uncheck all checkboxes on the form, it just unchecks checkboxes **Directly** on the form. If you might have chackboxes on panels, groupboxes, etc, you need to improve the code to recursively check for inner controls.

Comment: Likely @Alireza said , I have added some recursive code for you , helping it can help you to deal with your problem, thanks

Comment: @Alireza uhmm.. but I have no idea how to do it xD I'm new to programming vb.net

Comment: @merdolodafoca you should tell us what do you want or what kind of problems did you get , and then we can help, so that you have to tell us more detail about your questions

Comment: @willie ok. I just want uncheck all checkboxes in all the project forms (if are opened) by clicking a button. The form where I place the code isn't the startup form

Comment: @merdolodafoca I have modified a little be , when user open the form ,I close all checkbox attribute to disable and then user can not change anymore until you change statement, hopefully it is you want.

Comment: @willie thanks, but that code still doesn't work for me. It unchecks only the checkboxes in the form where the code is placed, I need to clear all the checkboxes in all the opened forms

Comment: @merdolodafoca could you give me your detail codes , not just a part of sample , i will try it for you, thank

Comment: @willie I have just updated the code in the question, thanks for you supprot

Answer (score 1):

Likely @Alireza said you need to recursive check for inner controls, Hopefully following is what you want,
Thanks,

For every form, you just need to insert

```
Dim x As New Class1     
x.TempClass(Me)
```

For example code

```
Public Class Form1
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim x As New Class1
            x.TempClass(Me)
        End Sub
End Class
```

and then you should create a new class for all CheckBoxs action, like below

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Function TempClass(ByRef form As Control)

        Dim allTxt As New List(Of Control)
        For Each txt As CheckBox In FindControlRecursive(allTxt, form, GetType(CheckBox))
            txt.Enabled = False
            txt.Checked = False
        Next
        Return form
    End Function



    Public Shared Function FindControlRecursive(ByVal list As List(Of Control), ByVal parent As Control, ByVal ctrlType As System.Type) As List(Of Control)
        If parent Is Nothing Then Return list
        If parent.GetType Is ctrlType Then
            list.Add(parent)
        End If
        For Each child As Control In parent.Controls
            FindControlRecursive(list, child, ctrlType)
        Next
        Return list
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: and for clearing the checkboxes? what command I have to use? Thanks

Comment: hi @merdolodafoca for this sample you dont need to do anything , because this function will find out all of checkboxs on your form

Comment: hi @merdolodafoca I have changed the code for you want ,good day